# Diff between ++*p and *p ++

Tags: c

```
int *p,x=5;
p=&x;
x=++*p;
printf("%d\n",x);
x=*p++;
printf("%d\n",x);
x=++*p;
printf("%d",x);
```

Though I know that prefix ++ first increment the value then stores it and postfix ++ first store the value then increment it. But in the last line why does it print 1 in the printf statement?

Comment: `*p++` advances the pointer, i.e. changes the address stored in `p`, so when you dereference it the next time it's UB.

Comment: After your first increment `p` is pointing to **something**, but it's not defined. It prints 1 because that's what it does when you run it this time.

Answer (score 0):

- `x=++*p;` changes the contents from 5 to 6, then stores 6 in x. (Prefix ++ and * have same precedence, so the operator associativity of prefix operators comes into play, which is right-to-left.)
- `x=*p++;` means that postfix ++ is evaluated first, since it has higher precedence. But the actual change of `p` will only happen after the whole expression is executed, so the value 6 from `*p` will be stored in x before that happens.

  Note that the ++ means that `p` now points one `int` beyond the actual valid memory location. This special case with pointing 1 item beyond what's allocated happens to be allowed in C, *as long as the variable isn't de-referenced*.
- `x=++*p;` here the pointer is de-referenced, which isn't allowed, so this is a bug (regardless of the ++). It's undefined behavior, anything can happen. For you it happens to print 1, this time. For me, it prints 8958, this time. But the program might as well crash or start behave in other random ways, since it's an undefined behavior bug.

Please note that it is bad practice to mix `++` with other operators in the same expression. The ++ operators are notoriously dangerous, since they introduce a side effect of writing, and this side effect might not sit well with the rest of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Lundin had a great, thorough answer. I hope this isn't too off-topic...

The last statement happens to be incrementing the pointer as an integer. You can see how `p` is incremented if you change your print statements to this.

```c
    printf("%d, %p\n",x,p);
```

With `gcc`, I have the following output:

```c
6,0x7ffeee3a92a4
6,0x7ffeee3a92a8
-298151255,0x7ffeee3a92a9
```

Here, you can see the pointers are incremented `sizeof(int)` (4-bytes) for the first two lines. However, undefined behavior happens in the last statement, which prints out garbage in my case because it's no longer 4B aligned. In this case, it happens to treat the pointer now as an int (since it's incrementing the value by 1 now).

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a better example:

```
int main()
{
    int *p,x[4]={1,2,3,4};
    p=x;
    ++*p;
    printf("%2d %2d %2d %2d\n",x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]);
    printf("p: %p x: %p\n", (void *)p, (void *)x);
    *p++;
    printf("%2d %2d %2d %2d\n",x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]);
    printf("p: %p x: %p\n", (void *)p, (void *)x);
    ++*p;
    printf("%2d %2d %2d %2d\n",x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]);
    printf("p: %p x: %p\n", (void *)p, (void *)x);
}
```

```
the output is
 2  2  3  4
p: 0x7ffc7ef56670 x: 0x7ffc7ef56670
 2  2  3  4
p: 0x7ffc7ef56674 x: 0x7ffc7ef56670
 2  3  3  4
p: 0x7ffc7ef56674 x: 0x7ffc7ef56670
```